# Liquid templating for Node.js

Tags: node.js

Does anyone know if there are any ports of [Liquid Templating](https://github.com/tobi/liquid) for Node.js? Or anything like it?

More or less our goal is to port [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) to Node.js - so anything to help with the templating side will be appreciated :)

Comment: Liquid looks like it has a syntax similar to Jinja2 or Django templates, so you might want to look for ports of those, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks guys.

Ended up using [eco](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco) as the templating engine.

For the layouts-in-layouts of Jekyll as well as the YAML headers of template files I coded my own: http://docpad.org

Answer (score 6):

There are a few versions in js I've run across - the only node-specific port I have seen is **[Liquid Node](https://github.com/sirlantis/liquid-node)** which is compatible with node's async programming

Answer (score 2):

As I said in a comment, it appears that Liquid has a syntax similar to Jinja2 or Django templates. Some people seem to have ported some of those templating languages:

- [Djangode](https://github.com/simonw/djangode) (see the templates part; it contains other things, too)
- [Strobe](https://github.com/skid/strobe-templates)

In addition, there seems to be a large collection of other templating languages on the [Node wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#templating).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few similar libraries with varying features, these are two that support inline filters:

- [ejs](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs)
- [dustjs](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/)

Comment: please. those are nothing like liquid, jinja or django-templates.